# Spring annotation for making two fields mandatory out of four data fields

Tags: spring

I have four data fields and i have to make sure that i receive data for at least two fields out of four. I am using spring 3 mvc and i wanted to know that if we have any annotation availabe in spring  which can be used to group this not null logic across four fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply creating a custom validator annotation in spring

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it by annotation [@NotEmpty](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/NotEmpty.html) of Hibernate Validator it will check value to be `not null` and `size is > 0`

This annotation is given on fields of bean for which you need to make it required fields.

On client side if your are using Spring form tag than there is attribute `modelattribute=BeanName` which map your form fields to Bean fields.

On controller side you need to validate this bean before proceed it further, for this you need to include `@valid` annotation before your bean object argument in controller as show below

```
public String submitForm(@Valid MyBean myBean, BindingResult result, Model m) 
{
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "formPage";  //return to error page or display error on client side
    }

    m.addAttribute("message", "Successfully saved form: ");
    return "formPage";
}
```

`result.hasErrors()` return true if fields value in invalid as per validation define in your bean class. It return false if all values are correct.

Here is complete example on [Validate Form fields in Spring MVC](http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/).